# Use ThreadLocal Webdriver in kotest for parallel execution

Tags: kotlin, thread-local, kotlintest, kotest

How does one use ThreadLocal Webdriver for parallel browser execution in kotest? Somehow I believe kotlin coroutines messes this up.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `ThreadLocal` doesn't always play nice with coroutines. A coroutine may resume on any thread that is owned by the `CoroutineDispatcher`.

I think the proper way about it would be to add your Webdriver as a Coroutine context element. Either [create your own context element](https://kt.academy/article/cc-coroutine-context#creating-our-own-context) or you can have a look at [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#thread-local-data), perhaps you can use that in conjunction with a [listener](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/listeners.html) ?